Can't get Dataverse ServiceClient to work properly in Azure Function
I have a set of HTTP-triggered functions in an Azure Functions app (.NET 8, isolated worker model) that integrate with Dynamics 365 using the Dataverse ServiceClient (v1.1.17). The issue I'm encountering is when I send multiple requests, the underlying HttpClient gets disposed of unexpectedly.
At first, I thought this issue was related to the lifecycle of the ServiceClient. However, I've tested it by registering it as both scoped and singleton, but there was no difference. I've tried creating a new instance and disposing of it after each use. I even tried a "trick" I found in the GitHub repo CdsWeb that wraps the client and creates a reusable instance copy.
I've run the same code in a fresh minimal API, and it works just fine. The same goes for running it inside a console app inside a loop. When load testing it with k6 (100 VUs for 20s) it results in 1 completed and 99 interrupted iterations. However, when implemented in a minimal API, it results in 100 completed and 0 interrupted iterations.
Running the function in Azure (consumption-based) produces the same error. It also regularly produces a TaskCanceledException.
This is a bare minimum test:
var query = new QueryExpression(entityName: "contact")
{
    TopCount = 1,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("contactid", "firstname")
};

// serviceClient injected as a singleton. Access token is cached in memory and reused.
var results = await serviceClient.RetrieveMultipleAsync(query);
var contactEntity = results.Entities.SingleOrDefault();

This is how the ServiceClient is setup:
// Adding it to servicecollection
services.AddSingleton<IOrganizationServiceAsync, ServiceClient>(provider =>
{
    var appSettings = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
    var cache = provider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();

    var managedIdentity = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        // Using Managed Identity running in Azure
        ManagedIdentityClientId = appSettings.Value.ManagedIdentityClientId,
        ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false,

        // Using Visual Studio/VS Code credentials for local devlopment
        ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = false,
        ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = false
    });
    var environment = appSettings.Value.DataverseInstanceUrl;

    return new ServiceClient(
            tokenProviderFunction: f => GetToken(environment, managedIdentity, cache),
            instanceUrl: new Uri(environment),
            useUniqueInstance: true);
});

// Getting access token and caching it for 50 minutes
async static Task<string> GetToken(string environment, DefaultAzureCredential credential, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    var accessToken = await cache.GetOrCreateAsync(environment, async (cacheEntry) =>
    {
        cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext([$"{environment}/.default"]));
        return token;
    });
    return accessToken.Token;
}


See connection string and Authentication Type : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect

@jdweng I am not sure what you’re asking me to see? I am not using a connection string. I´ve updated the question.

You are sending an HTTP message where you can only send one request and get back one response with each connection.  Make sure you are getting back a status 200 OK with each message to make sure the connection is closing properly.   You can reuse the token multiple times (until token expires).  So create the token than loop for each request.  Either you will get back a response with a status (200 OK, or 400/500 error), or you will get back an exception that the connection closed unexpectedly.   The token request and the message request should both return a status of 200 OK.

You said it works in the Fresh API.   What is target NET/CORE version of Fresh vs one that fails?  I've seen lots of case recently where Net 8 is failing.  Did you try Net 7?

The serviceclient are injected as a singleton to be reused between multiple requests and access token is cached. Am I doing it wrong here? The fresh API also running on .NET8. I have not tested it on .NET7 (yet).

Client can be reused if you call the constructor with 'new'.  I can't tell how you are looping with code posted.  The posted code looks like it gets a token and only one client for the every connection instead on creating a new client for each connection.

Could you please provide an example?

NuGet package Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client version 1.1.17 is built on .NET 6.0. It is important to note that it has a dependency on assembly System.Text.Json Version 7.0.0.0, which is part of .NET 7. However, .NET 7 is not available on Azure Functions servers. See this discussion on GitHub and on Power Apps Community Forums.
An easy fix would be to base your Azure Function project on .NET 6 and use NuGet package Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client version 1.1.14 instead of the latest.
Microsoft plans to add .NET 8 support at the end of this year.

I downgraded the functions project to .NET 6 and managed to process 1504 requests in 20 seconds. None were interrupted, so this approach seems to work. Thank you! I have been searching arount but missed that discussion on Power Apps Community Forums.
However, I still encounter some disposed exceptions when I cancel a request before the function has returned a response. I never experience this behavior in a plain web API or else in a function in general.

A ServiceClient instance is not thread safe. It cannot be used simultaneously by multiple requests. Use ServiceClient.Clone() to obtain separate IOrganizationService instances.
